# Postgresql: How to get a json where one column is the key and another column is the value?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have a table as follows. The `repliesto` is a unique and not null column and `devicetokens` is an array:

```
CREATE TABLE devices(
                     repliesto    TEXT PRIMARY KEY CHECK (repliesto <> ''), 
                     devicetokens TEXT[] NOT NULL 
                       CHECK (ARRAY_LENGTH(devicetokens, 1) IS NOT NULL 
                          AND ARRAY_LENGTH(devicetokens, 1) > 0)
);
```

Sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM devices ;
```

| repliesto | devicetokens |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | {a} |
| user2 | {b,c} |

I need to get a single json where `repliesto` column is the key and the `devicetokens` array is the value as follows:

```json
{"user1": ["a"], "user2": ["b","c"]}
```

I am able to use this:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(json_build_object(repliesto, devicetokens)) FROM devices;
```

But this gives me the following:

```json
[{"user1": ["a"]}, {"user2": ["b", "c"]}]
```

This is different from what I want as it's an array of each individual row as a json. I want a single json (not array) where the `repliesto` column is the key and the `devicetokens` array is the value. How can I do that?

Comment: The (no longer supported) Postgres 9.1 did not have any JSON support. If you really want to use JSON, you should upgrade to a maintained and supported version (e.g. 12 or 13) before you continue.

Comment: based on the fact the SELECT jsonb_agg returns data and not SQL syntax error the version of PostgreSQL must be 9.5+. sudoExclaimationExclaimation, please update the question tags. Please provide the PostgreSQL version you are working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL v9.5+ there is an aggregate function [json_object_agg(name, value)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html)

```
SELECT 
  json_object_agg(repliesto, array_to_json(devicetokens))
FROM 
  devices;
```

Result:

```
{ "user1" : ["a"], "user2" : ["b","c"] }
```

You are welcome to try it out in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=ad4f62f5cfd170652dc34acde1a8ec03)

Comment: Will try in few hours and get back to you.

Comment: This worked well. I had to add `COALESCE` to it for cases when the resulting JSON was empty. So: `SELECT COALESCE(json_object_agg(repliesto, array_to_json(devicetokens)),'{}') FROM devices where repliesto = ANY('{"user1","user6"}');`